# find and replace a line OR add to the end of the file

Tags: bash, sed

Is it possible to either find and replace a line in a file OR append a string to the end if it is not there?

I know I can use this to **find and replace**:

```
sed -i -e "s/^SEARCH/LINE 1\nLINE 2/" file
```

I know I can **append** to the file like this:

```
cat << EOF | tee -i file1 file2
LINE 1
LINE 2
EOF
```

Is it possible to somehow to combine this. So if `/^SEARCH.*$/` matches then replace it, if it doesn't, then append the replacement to the end of the file.

**Update with a better input/output example:**

For example, if I had this input file `testfile`:

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
```

Let's say I wanted to find and replace `Bravo` with `Bravo=bingo`, **OR** add `Bravo=bingo` if `Bravo` is not there, the expected output is:

```
Alpha
Bravo=bingo
Charlie
```

This is because `Bravo` exists in the file, so it is replaced.

Let's say I wanted to find and replace `Delta` with `Delta=bingo`, **OR** add `Delta=bingo` if `Delta` is not there, the expected output is:

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta=bingo
```

This is because `Delta` is not in the file so it is appended.

Comment: I'm not stuck on `sed`. Isn't SO/SE about the *best* way to do something? The way you showed works, and its especially useful for inserting something with multiple lines, but are you saying its the **best** way to do it if you don't need to insert multiple lines? If you are then I'll secede. The reason I want to re-open the question is to see if there is a better way to do this when you don't need to insert something with multiple lines.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm saying as it's clear, simple, portable, efficient, robust, and easy to enhance. idk what SO/SE means btw and couldn't find a definition for it by googling.

Comment: Your explanatory text doesn't match your sample outputs. You say you want to replace `^SEARCH=.*$` but this doesn't match your "Bravo" example. You say you want to append `Delta=bingo` but you actually append `Delta`.

Comment: @jhnc Oops. Sorry for the typos. I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk one-liner:

```
awk 'gsub(/^SEARCH/,"LINE 1\nLINE 2"){s=1}END{if(!s)print "LINE 1\nLINE 2"}1' file
```

This does not replace in-place though, if you want in-place change:

```
awk 'gsub(/^SEARCH/,"LINE 1\nLINE 2"){s=1}END{if(!s)print "LINE 1\nLINE 2"}1' file | tee file
```

Remember to escape the orginal and replacement if they contain `regex` characters, it's easier than change to match/substr method when the texts are not long.

Comment: So this basically tries to do the replace, and if it works it sets a variable, and if doesn't then it'll print that line in the end?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  Right.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan No matter replace works or not the lines will be print.  the `s` var is for determine append at last or not.

Comment: That will fail given various possible characters in the original and replacement texts. This problem needs to be solved with string operations, not regexps and back-reference enabled text.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  Check what Ed mentioned, if you do have such scenarios be careful and remember to escape (easier than change to match and substr etc if the text's not much).

Comment: @EdMorton  Thanks for mention it.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement part is exactly the same as at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504046/1745001 but here it is simplified for this specific use case and the tweak of appending if not found is done just by setting a flag if it's found and printing at the END if that flag isn't set:

```
awk 'BEGIN{new="LINE 1\nLINE 2"} /^SEARCH/{$0=new; f=1} {print} END{if (!f) print new}' file
```

Again the above is using strings for the replacement and so will work for any chars, the `/^SEARCH/` is a regexp since you don't appear to have regexp metachars but if you did you'd change that to `index($0,"SEARCH")==1` or similar to do a string rather than regexp match.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about a single `sed` command, but you can just have `sed` backup the file, then test the difference. If there is no difference, append to end of file:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/^SEARCH/LINE 1\nLINE 2/' file
diff file file.bak > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    sed -i -e '$aLINE 1\nLINE 2' file
fi
```

Comment: That last sed line would treat `$aLINE` as a shell variable that expands to null. Always use single quotes around strings and scripts unless you have a very specific NEED to use double quotes (e.g. to expose the script/string to the shell for variable expansion) and fully understand the implications and consequences. It'd fail in various ways given various values of SEARCH and each LINE, and calling multiple tools on the file is obviously a very inefficient approach (e.g. why do the first sed+diff instead of just one grep for SEARCH?).

Comment: Thanks, @EdMorton.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed one-liner:

```
sed -i 's/^SEARCH/LINE 1\nLINE 2/;ts;bt;:s;h;:t;${x;/./!{x;s/$/\nLINE 1\nLINE 2/;be};x};:e' file
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what all that does? I'm not able to follow/understand.